# What is the ratio of the turns in the transformer when it is impedance-matching?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance

I study physics on my own. There is a question in my textbook:

> A transformer may be used to provide maximum power transfer between two AC circuits that have diffirent impedances $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$. This process is called *impedance matching*. Show that the ratio of turns     $N_{1}/N_{2}$ for this transformer is
>   $\frac{N_{1}}{N_{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{Z_{1}}}{\sqrt{Z_{2}}}$

---

I tried to solve the problem with two equations: 
$$P=V_{1}I_{1}\cos\phi_{1}=V_{2}I_{2}\cos\phi_{2}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}=\frac{N_{1}}{N_{2}}\tag{2}$$

And I got:
$$\frac{N_{1}^{2}}{N_{2}^{2}}\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}=\frac{Z_{1}^{2}}{Z_{2}^{2}}$$

From the result, only when $\cos{\phi_{1}}=\cos{\phi_{2}}$, I could obtain the answer: $\frac{N_{1}}{N_{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{Z_{1}}}{\sqrt{Z_{2}}}$. But it should not be assumed that $\cos{\phi_{1}}=\cos{\phi_{2}}$. And I have read another [article](http://www.hunter.cuny.edu/physics/courses/physics222/repository/files/pdf/ElectronicsLab12.pdf). In the article, it replaced my equation one to
$$P=V_{1}I_{1}=V_{2}I_{2}$$

The power factors are ignored!

---

**Why the power factors of two diffirent AC circuits can be considered as the same when matching the impedance of the transformer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it should not be assumed that $\cos\phi_1=\cos\phi_2$.

For an ideal transformer, there is no other possibility than that $\phi_1 = \phi_2$

First, one can easily derive the impedance transformation of a transformer with just the voltage and current relationships:

$$V_1 = \frac{N_1}{N_2}V_2$$

$$I_1 = \frac{N_2}{N_1}I_2$$

Assuming the load has impedance $Z_L$, then

$$V_2 = I_2Z_L$$

and it immediately follows that

$$V_1 = \frac{N_1}{N_2}I_2Z_L$$

$$I_1 = \frac{N_2}{N_1}I_2$$

$$\Rightarrow Z_1 \equiv \frac{V_1}{I_1} = \left(\frac{N_1}{N_2}\right)^2Z_L$$

Now, the power delivered to the load impedance is (assuming rms phasors)

$$P_L = \mathrm{Re}\{V_2I_2^*\} = \mathrm{Re}\{|I_2|^2Z_L\} = |I_2|^2|Z_L|\cos\phi_L,\quad \phi_L = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{X_L}{R_L}\right)$$

and the power delivered to the primary is

$$P_1 = \mathrm{Re}\{V_1I_1^*\} = \mathrm{Re}\left\{|I_2|^2Z_L\right\} = |I_2|^2|Z_L|\cos\phi_L = P_L$$

Comment: How to derive $I_{1} = \frac{N_{2}}{N_{1}}I_{2}$? Because the derivatives of the magnetic fields at two solenoids are the same?

Comment: @IvenCJ7, for ideal coupling between the primary and secondary coils, *all* of the magnetic flux threading the primary threads the secondary and so $N_2I_2 = N_1I_1$

Comment: Did you mean that all of the magnetic field lines pass through the primary thread the secondary? If the magnetic fluxes through two coils are the same, the delta voltages of the two coils will be the same.

Comment: @IvenCJ7, I do actually mean magnetic flux; having the same flux $\Phi$ threading both coils doesn't guarantee that the 'delta voltage' will be the same.  For that to be the case, the coils must have the same flux *linkage* $\lambda = N\Phi $

Comment: I got it! It is as the same as what I meant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See a transformer does not change the phase of a transformed quantity(i.e.:-V, I) therefore the respective difference between their phases remains same:-phi1=phi2.;)